# Making a Triforce out of Triforces?

Tags: java

I have written a code to make a perfect triforce using for loops. How could I use more for loops to create a triforce out of these triforces?

**NOTE**: The "ROptionPane" is the same as "JOptionPane"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String rowsWantedAsSt = ROptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How big would you like the Diamond to be?",
            "Diamond", ROptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    int rowsWanted = Integer.parseInt(rowsWantedAsSt);


    //stars on the top row
    int starsWanted = 1;
    //spaces on the top row
    int spacesWanted = (rowsWanted * 2) + 3;





    for (int rows = 0; rows < rowsWanted; rows++) {
            for (int spaces = 0; spaces < spacesWanted; spaces++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int stars = 0; stars < starsWanted; stars++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
            starsWanted += 2;
            spacesWanted--;
    }
            starsWanted = 1;

            spacesWanted = rowsWanted + 1;

        for (int rows = 0; rows < rowsWanted; rows++) {
            for (int spaces = 0; spaces < spacesWanted + 2; spaces++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int stars = 0; stars < starsWanted; stars++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            for (double spaces = 0; spaces < (spacesWanted * 2) - 3; spaces++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int stars = 0; stars < starsWanted; stars++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
            starsWanted += 2;
            spacesWanted--;

        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you talking about? I think I know and that disturbs me but please, tell us.

Comment: As in a Triforce, made of three triforces

Comment: Want a Triforce?  Defeat Gannon.

Comment: I already have the triforce with this code. I want to implement more for loops to create a triforce made of 3 triforces.

Comment: @user270349 I'm morbidly curious: why does a Legend of Zelda reference "disturb" you?

Comment: sounds like you should look into converting your code to use recursive methods

Comment: @millimoose it makes me feel like a freak.

Comment: @user270349 zelda is awesome...I'm tempted to flame...

Comment: Are these simply Sierpinsky triangles?

Comment: @jackrabbit, Yes, the Triforce is a low-order Sierpinski triangle.

Comment: Worth noting: the same shape appears in many places around the world, including [5000 year-old swords](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/2012/06/worlds-oldest-swords-have-triforce-on-them/)

Answer (score 1):

The Triforce is identical to the result of the first iteration of an algorithm creating a [Sierpinski triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle). A Triforce made of Triforces would look like the second iteration of the algorithm.

Rosettacode.org has two different [Java implementations](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle#Java) of a function which will generate an ASCII Sierpinski triangle iteratively; you may want to start there.